# How to get time difference based on timezone?

Tags: javascript, typescript, date, time, timezone

I need to get time difference in hours and minutes of other user who is situated in anather country. Here is what i have done.

```ts
const timeZone = "Asia/tokyo"; // Time zone can be changed

let arr: any = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {
  timeZone: timeZone,
  dateStyle: "full",
  timeStyle: "full",
});

let currentTime = new Date();
```

Need to get difference between currentHour and arr

Comment: Date constructor doesn't accept an Array as an argument - your logic may also be flawed since the hours in the result will be 1 to 12 ... no indication of AM or PM

Comment: is the timeZone always Asia/Tokyo? If not, then what about timezones like `Asia/Calcutta` ... i.e. `UTC+5:30` or even `Australia/Eucla`

Comment: No, timeZone will change. i have just added a sample data there. Timezone can change based on users country.

Comment: well, then "currentHour" isn't going to be enough

Comment: I have added Asia/tokyo as an example. if the current time at japan is 1:30 pm and my current time is 11:00 am i need to get the hours and minutes difference.

Comment: Use [Temporal's `TimeZone`](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/#Temporal-TimeZone) (or a polyfill for it) and save you a lot of headaches. In particular, [get the offsets](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/timezone.html#getOffsetNanosecondsFor) (at the current instant, which I presume you're interested in) for both time zones and subtract them

Comment: What do you mean "or a polyfill" @Bergi - it's not available anywhere other than a polyfill :p

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Firstly, use `en-CA` locale for the "calculation" ... it outputs `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` which makes it simple to manipulate

Secondly, add `hour12: false` as you want 24 hour time

Then you can

```js
const minutesToHHMM = (m) => {
  const s = m < 0 ? '-' : '';
  m = Math.abs(m);
  const mm = (m % 60).toString().padStart(2, 0);
  const hh = Math.floor(m / 60);
  return `${s}${hh}:${mm}`;
}
const timeZone = 'Australia/Eucla'; // odd timezone to always show minutes in difference
const date = new Date();
date.setMilliseconds(0); // remove millisecond since we are not creating the "other" time with milliseconds
const other = new Date(...date
  .toLocaleString('en-CA', {
    timeZone,
    hour12: false,
  })
  .replaceAll('-',':') // convert yyyy-mm-dd to yyyy:mm:dd
  .replaceAll(', ', ':') // add ':' between date and time
  .split(':') // split all the values
  .map((v,i) => v - (i===1)) // subtract one from month
);

console.log("other time", other.toLocaleString());
console.log("local time", date.toLocaleString());
console.log("difference", minutesToHHMM((other-date)/60000));
```

My Typescript is inelegant ... but

```
const minutesToHHMM = (m:number) => {
  const s = m < 0 ? '-' : '';
  m = Math.abs(m);
  const mm = (m % 60).toString().padStart(2, "0");
  const hh = Math.floor(m / 60);
  return `${s}${hh}:${mm}`;
}
const timeZone = 'Australia/Eucla'; // odd timezone to always show minutes in difference
const date = new Date();
date.setMilliseconds(0); // remove millisecond since we are not creating the "other" time with milliseconds

const other = new Date(...(date
  .toLocaleString('en-CA', {
      timeZone,
      hour12: false,
  })
  .replaceAll('-',':') // convert yyyy-mm-dd to yyyy:mm:dd
  .replaceAll(', ', ':') // add ':' between date and time
  .split(':') // split all the values
  .map(Number)
  .map((v:number, i:number) => v - ((i===1) ? 1 : 0)) as []) // subtract 1 from month
);

console.log("other time", other.toLocaleString());
console.log("local time", date.toLocaleString());
console.log("difference", minutesToHHMM((+other - +date)/60000));
```

Tried that on a TS Playground, seems to work

Comment: Bro, how can we spread date here. I am getting error like A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter. Is this any issue with typescript?

Comment: Oh, sorry @coding.... ... I forgot you use typescript

Comment: @coding.... I've added my inelegant attempt at typescript - not idea how to use spread in typescript, it complains for no reason

Comment: @coding.... figured it out :p damn typescript is a wordy and fussy language

Comment: There is a issue with type in Ts code you provided, I have solved it and got the output. Thanks

Comment: oh, @coding.... ... where? the typescript playground had no issue with the code

Comment: Likely better to use *formatToParts* so you get the parts directly. Not sure if this works across DST boundaries.

Comment: @JaromandaX - This is a good start, but you'll find through testing that there are errors around the edge cases.  Specifically, because `other` is created by passing discrete numeric values to the `Date` constructor, it will be influenced by the DST rules of the local time zone.  Thus, it could be considered ambiguous or invalid if it's within a transition period of the local zone, even if it's a valid time in the "other" zone.  Libraries like Luxon start with this approach, but consider it only a guess.  Then they do some tests around the result to solidify the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is not a simple way to achieve this in JS today without using a library like Luxon (or equivalent complex code).  [Temporal](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal) should make this much simpler, when it's ready.

Comment: `because other is created by passing discrete numeric values to the Date constructor, it will be influenced by the DST rules of the local time zone` - but, that's what you want to do to get the difference in time between other and local

Comment: @JaromandaX—as Matt said, you're passing discrete values so might pass a date and time that either doesn't exist because it's in the "wind forward" hour or exists twice in the "wind back" hour. Also, the discrete values might be on the wrong side of the boundary.

Comment: @RobG - I thought `Date` was pretty smart - oh well, can't delete it as it's accepted

Comment: Hi bro, got an error in firefox and safari browser.

Comment: Odd, I tested this in firefox - anyway what is the error @coding....

Answer (score 0):

Solutions like that from Jaromanda X (reproduced below using *Intl.DateTimeFormat.formatToParts*) are OK, however better to pass an actual *Date* object rather than the date and time values.

I think it's more elegant to get the difference between the actual offsets (see lower).

```js
function msToHMS(ms) {
  let sign = ms < 0? '-' : '+';
  ms = Math.abs(ms);
  let z = n => (n < 10? '0':'') + n;
  let hr = (ms / 3.6e6) | 0;
  let min = ((ms % 3.6e6) / 6e4) | 0;
  let sec = ((ms % 6e4) / 1e3) | 0;
  return `${sign}${z(hr)}:${z(min)}:${z(sec)}`;
}

function getTZDiff(tz, d = new Date()) {
  let tv = d - (d % 1e3);
  let {year, month, day, hour, minute, second} = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', {
    year:'numeric', month:'numeric', day:'numeric',
    hour:'numeric', minute:'numeric', second:'numeric',
    timeZone: tz,
    hour12: false
  }).formatToParts(d).reduce((acc,part) => {
      acc[part.type] = part.value;
      return acc;
    }, Object.create(null)
  );
  return msToHMS(new Date(year, month-1, day, hour, minute, second) - tv);
}

console.log(getTZDiff('America/New_York', new Date(2023,3,2,1,30)));
```

Using timezone offsets:

```js
/* Return offset at loc for date
 * @param {string} loc - IANA representative location
 * @param {Date} date to get offset for
 * @returns {string} offset as ±hh:mm
 */
function getOffsetForLoc(loc, d = new Date()) {
  let offset = d.toLocaleString('en',{
    timeZoneName:'longOffset', timeZone: loc
  }).match(/[+|-][^+-]+$/); 
  return offset[0];
}

/* Convert offset in ±hh:mm:ss format to seconds
 * @param {string} offset - ±hh:mm:ss format
 * @returns {number} offset in seconds
 */
function offsetToSecs(offset) {
  let sign = offset[0] == '-' ? -1 : 1;
  let [hr, min, sec] = offset.match(/\d+/g);
  return sign * (hr*3600 + min*60 + (sec||0)*1); 
}

/* Convert secons to time in ±hh:mm:ss format
 * @param {number} secs - seconds to convert
 * @returns {string} equivalent in ±hh:mm:ss format
 */
function secsToHMS(secs) {
  let sign = secs < 0? '-' : '+';
  secs = Math.abs(secs);
  let z = n => (n < 10? '0':'') + n;
  let hr = (secs / 3600) | 0;
  let min = ((secs % 3600) / 60) | 0;
  let sec = secs % 60;
  return `${sign}${z(hr)}:${z(min)}:${z(sec)}`;
}

// Get diference in offset between two locations.
// Add difference to loc1 to get time in loc2
function getOffsetDifference(loc1, loc2, d = new Date()) {
  let off1 = offsetToSecs(getOffsetForLoc(loc1, d));
  let off2 = offsetToSecs(getOffsetForLoc(loc2, d));
  return secsToHMS(off2 - off1);
}

// Examples
let yourLoc = new Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
let cha = 'Pacific/Chatham';

console.log(
    `You  : ${yourLoc} ${getOffsetForLoc(yourLoc)}` +
  `\nOther: ${cha} ${getOffsetForLoc(cha)}` +
  `\nDiff : ${getOffsetDifference(yourLoc, cha)}` +
  ` (i.e. You + Diff == Other)` +
  `\nRev  : ${getOffsetDifference(cha, yourLoc)}` +
  ` (i.e. Other + Rev == You)`
);
```